# I am attempting to write a bash script to convert hex to base64

Tags: bash, command-line

I am attempting to do the matasano cryptopals challenges in bash.

The first step is [here](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1/)

I found [this stackexchange thread](https://superuser.com/questions/158142/how-can-i-convert-from-hex-to-base64) with a partial solution.

```
printf 49276d2 | xxd -r -p | base64
```

which produces `SSdt` as wanted.

I am looking to make a bash script so I can simply do

```
hexto64 49276d2
```

and get the same result. I'm not sure where to start after 
the #!/bin/bash . I have not found a similar example which takes arguments and pipes them through other commands and then outputs a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your script file named `hexto64`, simply write :

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "%s" "$1" | xxd -r -p | base64
```

And then you can use it as such :

```
hexto64 49276d2
```

Just so you know, `$1` means the first parameter you gave after the program name : `49276d2` in our case.

Comment: Needs to be executable (`chmod a+x hexto64`) and placed somewhere in the `PATH`. I favour `$HOME/bin/` myself but others might not.

Comment: Combing what you both said worked well. Thanks.